# Latitude and longitude UTM (Radian base) to decimal base - huh?

Tags: c#, math, gps, mapping, cartography

I'm recording data coming from some devices and I can't figure out how they are performing the conversion based on the following documentation:

LATITUDE (4213.2687N). Latitude in UTM (Radians base). In the database we store
that number in decimal base (42.221187)

LONGITUDE (00843.7684W). Longitude in UTM (Radians base). As the latitude, we
store that number in decimal base (-8.729533).

So I need to create a formula that takes: 4213.2687N, 00843.7684W and converts it to 42.221187, -8.729533. It seems like it should be easy but everything I try fails.

Help?

Comment: It looks like 13.2687 and 43.7684 represent minutes of arc. That gets you a lot closer to the values you indicate. So `42 + 13.2687/60` for example

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/UsefulData/UTMFormulas.HTM